# Publishing H.264 data from a Non-DirectShow video capture card to FMS(Red5) as live stream

Tags: video-streaming, publish, red5, rtmp, flash-media-server

I can't use FMLE(Flash Media Live Encoder) here because the video capture card is such a kind with no directshow support.

The video-capture-card captures the video and then encode the video to H.264 via the clips on the card.

The card provides some native interfaces so that I can write my app to get the data from the card and send the data to FMS/Red5 and then the FMS/Red5 streaming it.

My question is:
How to send the H.264 data to the FMS in RTMP protocol?

I have read the RTMP specification and I understand how to publish a live stream,

connect -> createStream -> publish -> metadata -> videodata

But I don't know what exactly I need to put for the metadata and video payload.
RSP ? NALU?

Any suggestion is welcome, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the source for RTMPD server (rtmpd.com) in order to find the advanced implementation for the RTMP protocol.
On the other hand, the solution to your problem could be as simple as using the librtmp library (dll form - from mplayer project) to publish your stream.

Good luck